# Move number line to another view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Hi everyone and good morning I am a noob, new with SwiftUI

I have table view (list) with name and line number and its work fine

I want when to join any name see the number in the second view

my code here

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var mynames = allDatabase
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(mynames[1 ... 4] , id: \.self) { namm in

                    NavigationLink(destination: DDetail(name: namm.name)) {

                        HStack(spacing: 5.0) {

                            Text("\(self.mynames.Index(of: namm)) -")
                            Text("\(namm.name)")

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DDetail: View {
    var name = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("This is Number :")
            Text(name)
        }
    }
}

struct Database: Hashable {
    var name: String
}

let allDatabase = [
    Database(name: "Joy1"),
    Database(name: "Joy2"),
    Database(name: "Joy3"),
    Database(name: "Joy4"),
    Database(name: "Joy5"),
    Database(name: "Joy6"),
    Database(name: "Joy7")
]
```

Comment: please try to clearify your question

Comment: I don't understand your question

Answer (score 1):

First of all be more specific when asking a question so people can help you more easily.

Anyway..

You are creating a new **name** in your **DDetail** which will result in an empty name. Because you want to pass data, there is no need to declare a new variable. The following code will fix this issue:

```
struct DDetail: View {

    // Edited following line:
    var name: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
           Text("This is Number :")
           Text(name)
        }
   }
}
```

If you want to pass the number and not the name use:

```
NavigationLink(destination: DDetail(name: self.mynames.firstIndex(of: namm)!))
```

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'Array<Element>.Index' (aka 'Int') to expected argument type 'String'

Comment: Parse name to String or use "\(self.mynames.firstIndex(of: namm)!))"

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
NavigationLink(destination: DDetail(name: namm.name)) {
```

With

```
NavigationLink(destination: DDetail(name:"\(self.mynames.firstIndex(of: namm)!)")) {
```